# Single vs Multiple SQL UPDATE performance using PHP PDO transactions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, transactions

I know that if we don't use PDO Transactions...

```
UPDATE table TABLENAME SET col1 = 'something1', col2 = 'something2' 
WHERE id= 3
```

will have a faster execution than:

```
UPDATE table TABLENAME SET col1 = 'something1' 
WHERE id = 3
UPDATE table TABLENAME SET col2 = 'something2' 
WHERE id = 3
```

but, what happens when we use PDO transactions? I think that wont matter if we use the first option or the second one in terms of performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to send less string length as SQL, because the stuff has to be parsed. Less SQL doing the same things == faster execution.

Also, you wouldn't need transactions when using the first form, while it would be absolutely necessary for the second one.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table TABLENAME SET col1 = 'something1', col2 = 'something2' WHERE id= 3
```

Will be the only **sensible** query. That's all, no further musings required.

Also, there is no such thing like "PDO transactions". there are only transactions supported by DBMS.

Comment: This still never Answers the question are transactional updates slower/faster then non transactional multiple statments(true his example was bad but the question is valid)